# <p:overlayPanel> with dynamic content is not updated properly

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, overlay

Clicking on any row of data table should show an overlay panel. The overlay panel itself has another data table (a custom component).

**Problem:** Suppose I click on row #2 for the first time, then data inside overlay panel is displayed properly. However, if I sort the column and click on row #2 on sorted data again, then same old overlay panel is displayed row #2 is now different due to sorting. Why is the overlay panel not being updated properly?

**Here is my code:**

**View:**

```
<p:dataTable value="#{dummyController.providerList}" var="m" id="multiple_claims_on_same_day_table" >

    <p:column sortBy="#{m.provider.name}" headerText="Name">
         <p:commandLink id="name_link" value="#{m.provider.name}" action="#?faces-redirect=true">
              <p:ajax listener="#{dummyController.onLinkClick(m.provider.rowIndex,m.provider.providerType)}"/>                                    
          </p:commandLink>

          <p:overlayPanel appendToBody="true"  for="name_link" dynamic="true" id="panel_for_federal_tax_number_link">
                <custom:dummy_data_table list="#{dummyController.multipleClaimsOnSameDayForAProviderList}">
                </custom:dummy_data_table>
                </p:overlayPanel>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

**Composite component:**

```
<composite:implementation>
            <p:dataTable value="#{cc.attrs.list}" var="m">
                <f:facet name="header">Detailed list of multiple claims sent on single date</f:facet>
                <p:column sortBy="#{m.provider.name}">
                    <f:facet name="header">Name</f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{m.provider.name}"/>
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
    </composite:implementation>
```

What is the proper solution so that I can display properly updated overlay panel with a data table from a custom component?